# Sharepoint On Premise with Azure Application insights

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, azure, monitoring

I have set up Application Insights in Azure and monitoring some SharePoint OnPremise sites. The monitoring only seems to be available for client side and it works fine, but i need know user id. I follow the manual from Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sharepoint

I still see a user that comes from the cookie and does not correspond to the sharepoint

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a 3 years old question, since nobody answer this. I shared in this thread just in case someone else (me too) also wants to know how to set this user name.

For client side to show user name, you need to set telemetry data (in this case) oninit event

> ai.user.id

This is what I have implemented to get user name and login name from SharePoint (Using SharePoint Server 2016 - Publishing Feature Activated).
In your master page (.html), add this 2 ScriptLink and 1 script tag before closing head tag (< /head>) like bellow.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" name="SP.js" runat="server" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="SP.UserProfiles.js" runat="server" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var personProperties; 

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs. 
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 

function getUserProperties() { 
    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance. 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext); 

    // Get user properties for the target user. 
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the 
    // getMyProperties method. 

    personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties(); 

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request. 
    clientContext.load(personProperties); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail); 
} 
function onRequestSuccess() {
    !function (T, l, y) { var S = T.<..CUT LONG SCRIPT, THIS SCRIPT CAN BE GOTTEN FROM https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS..> {
        src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
         onInit: function(sdk){
            sdk.addTelemetryInitializer(function (envelope){
                envelope.tags['ai.user.id'] = personProperties.get_displayName();//display User name ex:Ariwibawa
                envelope.tags['ai.user.authUserId'] = personProperties.get_accountName();//display login name ex:DOMAIN\Ariwibawa
            });
         },
        cfg: { // Application Insights Configuration
            instrumentationKey: "INSTRUMENTATION_KEY",
            enableDebug: false,
            loggingLevelConsole: 2
        }
    });
}
function onRequestFail(sender, args) { 
}
```

You need to get user name from SharePoint user profile, so this script wait until script **SP.UserProfiles.js** loaded completely. Call API current user and **onRequestSuccess** add displayName and accountName into telemetry data.

This is what you see in Application Insights.
[image: in Application Insights Page View Properties]